# how to align flutter draggable sheet

Tags: flutter, dart

here i try to code a draggable sheet in flutter .
here's the code

```
class DraggableSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  const DraggableSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 1,
        minChildSize: 0.6,
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController myScrollController) {
          return ListView.builder(
            controller: myScrollController,
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 +1000,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: const [
                    Icon(Icons.horizontal_rule),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    IndividCourseBar(
                      episode: '1',
                      caption: 'caption',
                      time: 23,
                      colorTheme: kLiteGreen,
                      duration: Durations1.mins,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    IndividCourseBar(
                      episode: '2',
                      caption: 'caption',
                      time: 23,
                      colorTheme: kLiteGreen,
                      duration: Durations1.mins,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    IndividCourseBar(
                      episode: '3',
                      caption: 'caption',
                      time: 23,
                      colorTheme: kLiteGreen,
                      duration: Durations1.mins,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    IndividCourseBar(
                      episode: '4',
                      caption: 'caption',
                      time: 23,
                      colorTheme: kLiteGreen,
                      duration: Durations1.mins,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    IndividCourseBar(
                      episode: '5',
                      caption: 'caption',
                      time: 23,
                      colorTheme: kLiteGreen,
                      duration: Durations1.mins,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    IndividCourseBar(
                      episode: '6',
                      caption: 'caption',
                      time: 23,
                      colorTheme: kLiteGreen,
                      duration: Durations1.mins,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    IndividCourseBar(
                      episode: '7',
                      caption: 'caption',
                      time: 23,
                      colorTheme: kLiteGreen,
                      duration: Durations1.mins,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and inside a stack i tried to call this widget here

```
container(
    scaffold(
        stack(
            children[
                ---lot of assets
                stack(
                    children[
                        container(
                            column(
                                children[
                                    //code for details text of course
                                ]
                            )
                        ),
                        //here i called the DraggableSheet
                        Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 -20),
                      const DraggableSheet(),
                    ],
                  ),
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
    )
)
```

and its working fine but look
[image]

when i get in to this page this loading on top of screen

but i actually want load bottom of the screen at first and can draggable to top
like this image when get in to page
[image]

how do i do that, I'm sorry if my question isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
Positioned(
   bottom: 0,
   left: 0,
   right: 0,
   top: ,//test different values here until it works
   child: Column(
      children: [
          Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 -20),
          const DraggableSheet(),
      ],
   )
)
```